# admin blade layout include dynamic select

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to include in my admin.blade.php layout a dynamic select with a model which I have created. Can you let me know how can I do it?

I know how to create the select dynamic but my main problem is how can i reference my model in admin.blade.php?

Thanks,

Comment: What a poorly worded / confusing question...

Comment: What have you tried, where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1- good** => you can always use @inject and here is the [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#service-injection).

**2- better** => you can add it to the boot method in the appServiceProvider and here is the [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers#the-boot-method).

**3- best** => you can pass that model from the controller to the view as an object like this

```
public function modelView(Model $model){
return view('admin.blade.php')->with([ 'model' => $model ]);
}
```

Comment: great! happy to be in help.